# Fixing PlatformException runtime error, how can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, youtube-player-flutter

I am using youtube_video_player package. But I am getting this PlatformException ERROR

[image]

I have to play videos from YouTube using video links

Comment: show the error message

Comment: Add you code as a code block text and post the error message as well